# Cant access Prime Music in Canada - redirects to Amazon.com

Tags: amazon, amazon-music

I have Amazon Prime in Canada.

- I'm logged into my Amazon.ca account
- I can login and access Prime Video in Canada.
- I try and access Prime Music, but am redirected to Amazon.com, where it logs me into my Amazon.com account, and says I have "No membership"

How can I fix this?

I've tried logging into my account from an incognito browser, with no help.

Comment: Is your device connecting via a US IP address? If so, Amazon may be redirecting you to the geographically appropriate Amazon URL.

Comment: Good point - but no, I'm not using any VPNs and am in Canada

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution turned out to be easy - I just called Amazon support, and they fixed it up within 10 minutes. I didnt think it'd be easy to reach their support and get such awesome response times, but I guess I was wrong.

So long story short - try the Amazon support customer line!
https://www.amazon.ca/gp/help/customer/

Answer (score 1):

I know this thread is a little old, but I'm posted in case this helps someone in the future.

- Go to the top right corner in your Amazon.ca account, and click "Your Account" under "Account & Lists".
- Under "Digital content and devices", click "Music Settings".
- Right at the bottom, you should see "Your Amazon Music Account is currently in US. Move your music account."
- Click on "Move your music account".
- You'll have the option to move it to Canada (or whatever other country you like).
- This change should take immediately.